# Animate() Not working in jQuery versions before 1.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

When I use a jQuery version before 1.2, animate() causes the error :

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

From the documentation I've read, it should be working in earlier versions with style and duration parameters, so I feel I must be doing something wrong.

For example, the following code runs correctly :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.2.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">

function dotheStuff(){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.width = '20px';
    div.style.height = '20px';
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    $(div).animate({marginLeft:'600px'}, 2000);
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="dotheStuff()">
</body>
</html>
```

While this code produces the error :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.1.4.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">

function dotheStuff(){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.width = '20px';
    div.style.height = '20px';
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    $(div).animate({marginLeft:'600px'}, 2000);
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="dotheStuff()">
</body>
</html>
```

The only difference is the version of jQuery.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please read this http://api.jquery.com/animate/ . Some of the animate features did not work before version X

Comment: Hey, I did read that, but, from what I'm seeing, the properties and duration values have been available since 1.0. I see specific versions for additions throughout, but nothing that would stop animate from working with these parameters in versions prior to 1.2. Is there something I'm missing? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you care though? 1.2 was released a very long time ago now

Comment: Just assume it's a bug that was fixed seven years ago.  What is the relevance of any of this?  Is your target audience stuck in 2006?

Comment: And which browser(s) are giving the error?  What method are you using for testing older browsers?  Emulation, Browser Mode?

Comment: A client of ours uses 1.1.3 and we are a 3rd party content provider adding a fairly extensive javascript application to their pages. Altering a larger portion of our code so we can dual load jQuery with noConflict is an option a little further down the road(I wasn't around when the current implementation was decided on and, from what I've heard, the dual load was causing an issue with some of our clients when it was first attempted a few of years ago), but if I can get these animations working with their version before then, we may retain the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd call it a bug which you can work around by dropping the units and making your value a Number:

`$(div).animate({marginLeft: 600}, 2000);`